# Google API subscribe a user to a calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, service-accounts

My PHP code uses a service account to create a new user in G Suite/Google Workspace.
That part is working fine, but then I'd like to auto-subscribe the new user to some of our standard office calendars. When I run the following code, the calendar is added to the service account's list, not the new user.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("CalendarID");
$calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
```

Is there anyway to insert into anther users calendarList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service account has its own google calendar account any actions you preform will be preformed on the service accounts google calendar account.

However if you want to impersonate a user when you declarer your client you need to ensure that you add the subject or the person who you wish to impersonate.

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
Set the scopes required for the API you are going to call
$client->addScope(Google\Service\CALENDAR::CALENDAR);
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
```